# Change property name of objects

Tags: javascript

An array of about 5 or more javascript objects in this format `[{'a':'man', 'age':'35'},{'b':'woman', 'age':'30'}]` needs to be converted to `[{gender:'man','age':'35'},{gender:'woman','age':'30'}]`.

What is an efficient way to do it?

**edit**
Also the input array may be like this where the keys are switched around:
`[{'a':'man', 'age':'35'},{'age':'30', 'b':'woman'}]` where a, b, ... could be anything and the objects in the array could up to 10 objects.

Comment: Is it always `a` and `b` or do you have to check the value ?

Comment: Efficient compared to what? What are you doing right now that you perceive to be insufficient?

Comment: What's wrong with @NinaScholz answer then?

Comment: So `a` and `b` could be anything, but are there other properties than `age` in those objects, and if so, how do you propose we'd filter them out ?

Comment: @adeneo No, there is no other property than age.

Comment: while looping check for 'man' and 'woman'. then change the associated key name to 'gender'.. simple :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could iterate the array and iterate the keys and change only the unknown key to `gender`.

```js
var data = [{ a: 'man', age: '35' }, { b: 'woman', age: '30' }];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k !== 'age') {
            o.gender = o[k];
            delete o[k];
        }
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: it's amazing to me that there's no way to just directly change a property name.

Answer (score 7):

You can iterate through original array and map fields you have to fields you need:

```js
var array=[{'a':'man', 'age':'35'},{'b':'woman', 'age':'30'}];
var newArray = array.map(function(item){
   return {
     age: item.age,
     gender: item.a || item.b
   };
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: This is a decent way to do it, given that the properties in question will always have a truthy value, which seems to be the case. Though a better explanation than *"other way"* would be good.

Comment: @squint the keys a,b could be too many to use the `||` operator and they are not known in advance.

Comment: Take a look to @NinaScholz answer

Comment: @FredJ.: *"...and they are not known in advance"* That would've been good to include in your question from the start. So do we know that the objects will never have more than two properties, one of which is unknown and the other of which is `age`?

Comment: @squint, Yes. that is correct, One is age and the other is unknown.

Comment: @FredJ.: in that case: `arr = arr.map(o =>
  ({age: o.age, gender: (delete o.age, o[Object.keys(o)[0]])})
)` should do the trick with minimal code, assuming the properties are enumerable. If enumerable is not guaranteed, then `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)[0]` should be used instead. The reason we can safely get the property that way is because we deleted the `.age`, so only one is left.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` method which accepts as parameter a `callback` function.

Also, you have to use `Object.keys(item)[0]` in order to get the first key.

```js
var array=[{'a':'man', 'age':'35'},{'b':'woman', 'age':'30'}];
console.log(array.map(function(item){
      return {gender: item[Object.keys(item)[0]],age:item.age};
}));
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `Object.keys` will give the property you expect in the `0` position.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have come up with suggestions, this is how I would do it:

I would map the keys, to the correct keys `a|b => gender, age => age`
Or define a function, which should give me the right key, based on the value (or type)..

Simple Mapping

```
const keysMap = {
  gender: ['a', 'b'],
  age: 'age'
};

// get it once.
const rightKeys = Object.keys(keysMap);
const rightKeysLen = rightKeys.length;

function getRightKeyBy(key) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rightKeysLen; i++ ) {
    const condition = keysMap[rightKeys[i]];
    if (key === condition || 
      (condition instanceof Array && condition.indexOf(key) > -1)) {
      return rightKeys[i]
    }
  }
  // if no better key was found return the initial key
  return key;      
}

function convertKeys(obj) {
   const newObj = {};
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
     newObj[getRightKeyBy(key)] = obj[key];
   });

   return newObj;
}


var array = [{a: 'men', age: '25'},{b: 'woman', age: '35'}];
var correctArray = array.map(convertKeys);

console.log(correctArray);
```